# How do I add search parameters to search page url?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to change the search results url from `/searchhandler` to `/searchhandler?search_string=[search string]` so that I can redirect to that search results page. How do I do this?

This is the search form in Search:

```
self.response.out.write("""
<form name="search_form" action="/searchhandler" method="post"><br />
<input type="text" name="search_string" size=40>
<input type="submit" value="search tags">
</form>""")
```

and this is the SearchHandler:

```
class SearchHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
...

s = filter(None, f1.striplist(self.request.get("search_string").split(" ")))                
n = len(s)

if n==1:
    query = Main.all()
    query.filter("tag_list", s[0])
    query.order("-total_value")

    f1.display(query, self)            
...
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to MattoTodd. Below is my solution according to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456670/how-do-i-add-search-parameters-to-search-page-url/7458896#7458896):

I changed the form like this:

```
search_string = ""
    self.response.out.write("""

    <form name="search_form" 
          action="/searchhandler?search_string=%s" 
          method="get">

     <br />
    <input type="text" 
           name="search_string" 
           size=40>
    <input type="submit" 
           value="search tags">
    </form>        
    """ % search_string)
```

Comment: You don't need to include the search string in the form URL - in fact, you shouldn't, since it'll just be replaced by the text the user enters. All you have to do is change the method from get to post.

Comment: Also, you really should use a templating library - you'll find it's _much_ easier than embedding your output in your code, and also easier to maintain.

Comment: Nick, thanks! I removed the url from the form. I don't understand how it really works because when it is a link I need to pass the url, for instance, like this:`<a href="/comment?url=%s">comments</a>`. For templates, for now I find it easier without templates, it makes more sense to me to see all the code in one file. Thanks again.

Comment: You should read up about basic HTML, HTTP and forms. When you submit the form, your browser sends the user to the URL you specified in the form's 'action' parameter, with the values from the form fields appended on as get parameters (eg, foo=bar&baz=bleh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the "tag_list" property a list of strings? I'm gonna assume you are trying to search for tags? I would use a comma delimited list for input,  instead of space delimited.

Also not sure what f1 is

Try this:

```
self.response.out.write("""
<form name="search_form" action="/searchhandler" method="GET"><br />
<input type="text" name="search_string" size=40>
<input type="submit" value="search tags">
</form>""")
```

and the handler:

```
class SearchHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        search_string = self.request.get("search_string", None)
        if not search_string:
            raise Exception("Missing Param")
        tags = [t.strip() for t in search_string.split(",")]
        if tags:
            query = Main.all()
            query.filter("tag_list IN", tags)
            query.order("-total_value")

        # Handle your results
```

EDIT: in that case make the request method GET instead of POST

Comment: Thanks, and sorry my question was not clear. I am actually trying to have the url for the search handler to contain the search_string (like in google search results). Because when I want to refer to that search result page `/searchhandler` is not enough; it needs to have the search_string like `/searchhandler?search_string=[search string]`.

Comment: EDIT: In that case use a GET request instead of POST